# Types are incompatible when using object spread

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am facing a strange error in typescript, which I couldn't find on the internet.

```
type IDialogTypeProps = 'info' | 'alert' | 'success' | 'warning';

  interface IDialogProps {
    text: string;
    type: IDialogTypeProps;
  }

  const obj = {type: 'warning'}

const dialog:IDialogProps = {
  text: 'string',
  ...obj,
}
```

Typescript throughs a warning about that

> ```
> Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IDialogTypeProps'
> ```

But when if I put ***type: string*** directly in the dialog object, typescript will compile without warnings. I am sure this is a pretty easy issue to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `obj` object, without being given an explicit type, is assumed by Typescript to be:

```
const obj: {
  type: string;
}
```

You can force TS not to automatically widen the inferred type from `'warning'` to `string` by denoting the `'warning'` string as `const`. Change `obj`'s definition to:

```
const obj = { type: 'warning' as const }
```

Comment: I agree with @CertainPerformance, you can also explicitly assign the type to 'IDialogTypeProps' in obj. Example const obj = { type: 'warning' as IDialogTypeProps }